# Convert DATETIME to Unix Epoch in Informix

Tags: sql, informix, datediff

I have a DATETIME column:

`SELECT mytime FROM mytable;`

```
mytime
--------------------
1/6/2013 10:41:41 PM
```

I would like to write a SQL statement that returns the time in Unix Time format (seconds since Unix Epoch - 01/01/1970 00:00:00) as `INTEGER`. I have tried to use `DATEDIFF` and `CAST` but no luck. This is **Informix** database.

Comment: What is the type of the `mytime` variable, because that is a non-standard format that the result is being presented in (and it's a gruesome format, too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `mytime` column is a DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND column (despite the formatting shown in the question), then the following stored procedure does the job.  It has more comment than procedure, but the comments explain what it is doing.

```
{
#   "@(#)$Id: tounixtime.spl,v 1.6 2002/09/25 18:10:48 jleffler Exp $"
#
# Stored procedure TO_UNIX_TIME written by Jonathan Leffler (previously
# jleffler@informix.com and now jleffler@us.ibm.com).  Includes fix for
# bug reported by Tsutomu Ogiwara <Tsutomu.Ogiwara@ctc-g.co.jp> on
# 2001-07-13.  Previous version used DATETIME(0) SECOND TO SECOND
# instead of DATETIME(0:0:0) HOUR TO SECOND, and when the calculation
# extended the shorter constant to DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND, it added the
# current hour and minute fields, as documented in the Informix Guide to
# SQL: Syntax manual under EXTEND in the section on 'Expression'.
# Amended 2002-08-23 to handle 'eternity' and annotated more thoroughly.
# Amended 2002-09-25 to handle fractional seconds, as companion to the
# new stored procedure FROM_UNIX_TIME().
#
# If you run this procedure with no arguments (use the default), you
# need to worry about the time zone the database server is using because
# the value of CURRENT is determined by that, and you need to compensate
# for it if you are using a different time zone.
#
# Note that this version works for dates after 2001-09-09 when the
# interval between 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 and current exceeds the
# range of INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND.  Returning DECIMAL(18,5) allows
# it to work for all valid datetime values including fractional seconds.
# In the UTC time zone, the 'Unix time' of 9999-12-31 23:59:59 is
# 253402300799 (12 digits); the equivalent for 0001-01-01 00:00:00 is
# -62135596800 (11 digits).  Both these values are unrepresentable in
# 32-bit integers, of course, so most Unix systems won't handle this
# range, and the so-called 'Proleptic Gregorian Calendar' used to
# calculate the dates ignores locale-dependent details such as the loss
# of days that occurred during the switch between the Julian and
# Gregorian calendar, but those are minutiae that most people can ignore
# most of the time.
}

CREATE PROCEDURE to_unix_time(d DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(5)
                                DEFAULT CURRENT YEAR TO FRACTION(5))
            RETURNING DECIMAL(18,5);
    DEFINE n DECIMAL(18,5);
    DEFINE i1 INTERVAL DAY(9) TO DAY;
    DEFINE i2 INTERVAL SECOND(6) TO FRACTION(5);
    DEFINE s1 CHAR(15);
    DEFINE s2 CHAR(15);
    LET i1 = EXTEND(d, YEAR TO DAY) - DATETIME(1970-01-01) YEAR TO DAY;
    LET s1 = i1;
    LET i2 = EXTEND(d, HOUR TO FRACTION(5)) -
                DATETIME(00:00:00.00000) HOUR TO FRACTION(5);
    LET s2 = i2;
    LET n = s1 * (24 * 60 * 60) + s2;
    RETURN n;
END PROCEDURE;
```

Comment: It does not work correctly, yesterday has a higher value than today.
                                    
EXECUTE PROCEDURE to_unix_time('2020-05-14 10:50:10') 5490414400
EXECUTE PROCEDURE to_unix_time('2020-05-14 21:50:10') 9450414400
EXECUTE PROCEDURE to_unix_time('2020-05-15 10:50:10') 5490500800
EXECUTE PROCEDURE to_unix_time('2020-05-15 21:50:10') 9450500800

Comment: @Max — please send me an email (see my profile). I can't reproduce your results (Informix 12.10.FC6 (64-bit) running on MacBook Pro with macOS 10.14.6 Mojave). I get these values for those four calls: 1589453410, 1589493010, 1589539810, 1589579410 (though each was reported with 5 zeros after a decimal point).  Which version of Informix are you using, running on which platform? The values you quote correspond to times in the years 2143 and 2269, which is puzzling.  However, this can't be discussed sensibly in comments, and adding to the answer would double its size and only cause confusion.

Comment: My VERSION era 9.50C1

Comment: How did you deduce that the version is `9.50C1`?  One way is to use `SELECT DBINFO('version', 'full') FROM informix.systables WHERE tabid = 1`.  The release that was originally going to be 9.50 was reversioned to version 10.00.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this using a simpler approach on version 14.10? In my case, I am not able to create a SP. Is there a direct date function to convert datetime to epoch?

Comment: @ArdaSavran: well, you can write it all in a single expression which you embed into an SQL statement, but it is far from pleasant to read or write.  To convert a column `d` (type assumed to be `DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(5)`, but it will work with most other (sane) variants that include year and day), the expression might be: `((EXTEND(d, YEAR TO DAY) - DATETIME(1970-01-01) YEAR TO DAY)::INTERVAL DAY(9) TO DAY)::CHAR(15)::DECIMAL(18,5) * 86400 + ((EXTEND(d, HOUR TO FRACTION(5)) - DATETIME(00:00:00.00000) HOUR TO FRACTION(5))::INTERVAL SECOND(6) TO FRACTION(5)::CHAR(15))::DECIMAL(18,5)`. Ugh!!!!

Comment: You can simplify that a little, but it's a direct transcription of the expressions in the stored procedure with some implicit casts made explicit. You can't convert an interval directly to a numeric type; you must use a string intermediary type, which makes the already verbose syntax even more verbose. Using the `CAST(expression, <new_type>)` notation instead of the `expression::<new_type>` notation is even more verbose, of course. If you only use DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND, you can modify the code to avoid fractions, but you need to use DECIMAL or BIGINT to avoid overflows with plain INTEGER.

Comment: I observe that since I wrote the preamble commentary to the stored procedure (in 1998), most Unix systems now work with a 64-bit `time_t` type instead of the older 32-bit type.  The 32-bit type could only represent times between `1901-12-13 13:45:52` and `2038-01-18 20:14:07`; the 64-bit type can represent a far vaster range (age of the universe with a bit to spare).  Those types are integers though; fractional seconds are still handled separately — e.g. with `struct timespec` which uses a `time_t` element for the seconds and a `long` integer to represent the nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Function `dbinfo('utc_current')` returns epoch time (number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).

Comment: True, but it only returns the Unix timestamp for the current time, not an arbitrary time as the question asks.