# Informix: Convert interval datetime to number of seconds

Tags: sql, informix

I want to convert intervals like 0 00:00:01 resulting from date1-date2 to number of seconds.

Does anyone know how to do it please? It is something similar to epoch in Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Given a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE times
(
    date1    DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL,
    date2    DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO times VALUES('2021-10-03 22:19:37', '2021-10-04 02:47:52');
```

You can get a number of seconds between the two values in various ways, including:

```sql
SELECT date1, date2,
       date2 - date1 AS diff_2_1_ivds,
       date1 - date2 AS diff_1_2_ivds,
       (date2 - date1)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND AS diff_2_1_ivss,
       (date1 - date2)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND AS diff_1_2_ivss,
       (date2 - date1)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10) AS diff_2_1_vc,
       (date1 - date2)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10) AS diff_1_2_vc,
       (date2 - date1)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER AS diff_2_1_int,
       (date1 - date2)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER AS diff_1_2_int
  FROM times;
```

Yes, it is necessary to convert to a character type (I used VARCHAR(10)) before converting to a numeric type.  This runs into problems if the difference between the two times is 1 billion seconds or more — which corresponds to a bit over 31 years.  There are other techniques that must be used for longer time periods.

#### Sample output:

| date1 | date2 | diff_2_1_ivds | diff_1_2_ivds | diff_2_1_ivss | diff_1_2_ivss | diff_2_1_vc | diff_1_2_vc | diff_2_1_int | diff_1_2_int |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND | DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND | INTERVAL DAY(8) TO SECOND | INTERVAL DAY(8) TO SECOND | INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND | INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND | VARCHAR(10) | VARCHAR(10) | INTEGER | INTEGER |
| 2021-10-03 22:19:37 | 2021-10-04 02:47:52 | 0 04:28:15 | -0 04:28:15 | 16095 | -16095 | 16095 | -16095 | 16095 | -16095 |

You can find a related question and answer at [Convert DATETIME to Unix Epoch in Informix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14187569/15168).  That shows the technique that must be used if the time gaps can be larger than 31 years.